# Probability distribution of a random variable X

Tags: probability, measure-theory

$X:([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda) \rightarrow\left([0,2], \mathcal{B}([0,2])\right.$ a random variable  defined as $X(\sigma)=2 \sigma^{3}$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Give the probability distribution, i.e. $\mathbb{P}_X$, of X.
How do I have to find the probability distribution in this case? I can imagine that it is not difficult but I do not get it.

Comment: Just follow the definition of $P_X$: $P_X(X \leq x)  = Leb(X \leq x) = Leb(2\sigma^3 \leq x) =\cdots$.

Comment: Then I try to isolate $\sigma$? I have never used the Lebesgue measure in such a way that's why I'm a bit lost.

Comment: My idea was to isolate $\sigma$ to get something like $Leb(\sigma \leq a)$ Then we know that $\sigma \in [0,a], if a < 1$? and thus $Leb( \sigma \in [0,a])$ is the length of the interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conciseness, denote $P_X(x)$ by $F(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and denote the Lebesgue measure by $\lambda$.

When $0 \leq x < 2$, direct application of distribution's definition gives that
\begin{align*}
F(x) = \lambda(X \leq x) = \lambda(2\sigma^3 \leq x) = \lambda(0 \leq \sigma \leq (x/2)^{1/3}) = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{1/3}.
\end{align*}

For completeness, state the final result as
\begin{align*}
F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0, \\
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{1/3} & 0 \leq x < 2, \\
1 & x \geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok I actually found the right probability by your explanations above thanks!

Comment: You may consider accepting the answer if it helps.